# Spotfire: Grouping rows in a table by columns

Tags: compression, grouping, calculated-columns, spotfire

I have three calculated columns in my table. How do I group the data so that I have one row per Department that shows the Head of Department and the values of the three calculated columns.

I made a mock dataset seen here [Data Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2r5Ic.png)

And here is what I want the data to look like after [Data After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R14Ct.png)

Comment: Personally, I'd probably handle it in a data function but the purely GUI approach would be to do it via a pivot.

Check out File -> Add Data Tables -> From Current Analysis and then use a pivot transformation.

Comment: Thanks! I am in-database so I would prefer to use a data function but am not sure how to go about it

Answer (score 0):

You can simply display a cross table, with

Horizontal as (Column Names), which if you type it within Properties as an expression corresponds to  <[Axis.Default.Names]>

Vertical as Department and then Head of Department, which corresponds to the expression <[Department] NEST [Head of Department]>

Cell values as the expression:
Avg([Calculated1]) as [Calculated1], Avg([Calculated2]) as [Calculated2], Avg([Calculated3]) as [Calculated3]